# Need a word that has the opposite meaning of "nominal"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm looking for a word that has the opposite meaning of the word *nominal* in the sense of *in name only*.

Here's an example (fill in the blank).

> Brian was in charge of scheduling in his [    ] role as Project Manager.
>   He was often expected to carry out Project Management duties, even though his business card identified him as a programmer.

*De facto* sort of works, but I feel like the connotation of (in my example) having the role by tradition or default doesn't fit what I am trying to say.

I am essentially looking for a term that means *we don't call it that, but in practice it really is*.

Comment: Obligatory economics joke: inflation-adjusted.

Comment: How about anominal? Not anonymal, and not an animal, nor an anonymal nominally mammalian animal. Okay, I'm done.

Comment: In some senses 'substantial' can also work.

Comment: "Unofficial" .....

Comment: If you are asking a question here, presumably it means you have english-language sensitivities. If you have english-language sensitivities, I am surprised the title of your question ends with a question-mark instead of a period. I can't say for sure, but it seems to me that ending a statement with a question-mark is not proper english.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think "We don't call it that, but in practice it really is" is a pretty good definition for [*de facto*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/de%20facto).

> actual; especially: being such in effect though not formally recognized

Comment: In some contexts, *virtual* might work too. "*What with doing all the scheduling and conflict resolution and interfacing with upper management, Brian became a virtual Project Manager, even though his business card still just said 'Programmer'.*"

Comment: @tchrist: your edit made it ambiguous as to *which* quote you're attributing to Merriam-Webster. I would think the link is attribution enough: even if the destination goes away, the link will still tell you where it used to lead.

Comment: A link is not an attribution. **People should not need a link to figure out where you are copypasting from.**  Please always provide the name of where you got these copy-pasted citations from.  See the meta question on [What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion about this.

Comment: @tchrist: in what way is this answer in any way "copypasting"? ("Copypasting" is defined as providing an answer that is 100% quoted, with no additional input. It's really not a nice thing to say about someone's post.)

Comment: What’s the part in quotes — that is, *actual; especially: being such in effect though not formally recognized* — if it is not copypasting?  And where is that citation from?

Comment: @tchrist: also, that link to the meta thread (which *you* posted) is rather disingenuous, because you're implying that your opinion is the accepted consensus. In actual fact, to the degree that there *is* any consensus so far (it's a bit early), it's that an author's name citation is **not** required for dictionary quotations.

Comment: Please post an answer there, not a comment here. As for consensus, we have not heard from almost anyone yet.  And does it truly surprise you that it is the very people most guilty of posting so-called “answers” that are absolutely nothing but copypasted dictionary definitions are the ones screaming the loudest about how much it terribly inconveniences them to actually say where they are copypasting from?  Most of one’s answer should be one’s own text, and copypasted dictionary entries are anything but that.

Comment: I wasn’t talking about you, sheesh.

Answer (score 8):

Actual? Effective? In this case I'd simply put:

> Brian was in charge of scheduling in
>   his role as project manager. He
>   was often expected to carry out
>   project management duties, even though
>   his business card identified him as a
>   programmer.

You can't be a Project Manager if you're not a Project Manager, but you can be a project manager if you just manage a project. In the former, you're stating a wishy-washy claim to a title, but in the latter you're simply relating a part of your job.

Comment: Effective kind of works, but it doesn't have the exact feel that I'm looking for. Still +1 for a workable answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think a minor rephrasing makes *de facto* the best choice:

> Brian was in charge of scheduling in his role as de facto Project Manager. He was often expected to carry out Project Management duties, even though his business card identified him as a programmer.

Answer (score 5):

It's a long phrase but you can also use "in everything but name"

> Brian was in charge of scheduling,
>   being the Project Manager in
>   everything but name. He was often
>   expected to carry out Project
>   Management duties, even though his
>   business card identified him as a
>   programmer.

Comment: Interestingly, it also reads well repunctuated as: *'Brian was in charge of scheduling.  Being the Project Manager in everything but name, he was often expected to carry out Project Management duties, even though his business card identified him as a programmer.'*

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/nominal?show=0&t=1291418614) lists the following antonyms (and near antonyms) of *nominal*: material, actual, real, true.

Answer (score 1):

*Tacit*.  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tacit) has this definition:

> **tacit** ADJECTIVE Understood or implied without being stated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I've added a link to a dictionary definition of _tacit_ that matched yours (except that it also adds the phrase "without being stated" to the end of the definition). At this site we try to provide reference-work support for definitions of words suggested in response to single-word requests. Thanks!

Comment: Word.   See what i did there?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something along the lines of "practical" or "practiced." "Assumed" might work better in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible alternatives are *supposed, putative, notional, theoretical* and *ostensible.*

Answer (score 0):

The most fitting antonym to nominal (or any other word for that matter) usually emerges from contextual usage. From the information you have provided, de facto seems the most apt. If you are allergic to Latin, you may try 'factual' or 'substantive.' However, make sure your ultimate choice blends with your contetual usage.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what point you are trying to make. Is this a positive bragging point or indicating he was put upon to do this extra task?
If it's for bragging rights, try:
Though Brian’s business card identified him as a programmer, his role was often expanded to include Project Manager duties, as one was being in charge of scheduling.
If it was a burden, try:
Brian’s business card identified him as a programmer, but he was often expected to carry out some project manager duties. He was put in charge of doing the scheduling.
For more bland, try:
Brian was often expected to carry out Project Management duties, like being in charge of scheduling, but his business card identified him as a programmer.

Also, as nominal means supposed, so-called, token, insignificant, assumed, considered, expected, try looking up opposites of these in a thesaurus. I just used the 1 in my word processer.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather use the word **maximal**:

> Brian was in charge of scheduling in his maximal role as Project Manager.
>   He was often expected to carry out Project Management duties, even though his business card identified him as a programmer.

As the word **nominal** means **existing in name only**. The word **maximal** being an exact antonym brings out the apt meaning into the sentence.

Comment: That's not what [maximal](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+maximal) means at all. _Maximal_ has no connotation of reality vs named.

Answer (score -2):

*Official, assigned, ex-officio, working, expert*?

Comment: "Official, assigned, ex-officio" are the opposite of what OP's final sentence tells us is sought.